# Making file wrap around when using fwrite

Tags: c, linux, embedded, ramdisk

I am using an embedded system running linux.I use a ramdisk filesystem on the embedded target.
My application captures real-time data and does Standard C "fwrite" to a file in this ramdisk fs.As there is limited amount of memory , I would like to set a max size for the file and cause fwrite to wrap around like a circular buffer. Is there a way to do this in manner that is transparent to the application ? 
I would prefer the application to remain unchanged when I migrate to a filesystem on a storage device (eSATA) having much larger capacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built in method of achieving this.

The best option is probably to write a small wrapper function that takes care of the file write while maintaining a count of the number of bytes written.

Once it has reached the maximum size that you set it should call `rewind()` (or `fseek()` etc.) to go back to the start of the file.

---

It might be easier to use `mmap()` to memory map your file and then treat it like a circular buffer. But again you would need to implement the wrapping yourself.